# get event on title bar using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I need any method to bind event on title bar.

I'm tried this

> root.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: print(e) )

but it not work in title bar

```
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()
root.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: print(e))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use the `master.bind('<Configure>',lambda event:print('Hello'))` but its very sensitive

Comment: Thanks, it is useful

Comment: @CoolCloud: what do you mean by "sensitive"?

Comment: @BryanOakley Even the slightest movement will trigger the callback, yes i know this is how its supposed to work. Such response rate, might not be what the OP is looking for.

Comment: by using '<Configure>' i can now if draging wind and i can stop chart animation in program It causes lag when moving the window

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can't bind any events on the titlebar. However, you can request a callback when the window is closed or minimized via `wm_protocol`.

Comment: thx, specifically I need to do some operations while moving the window

Comment: @Robox404: if that's the case, that's what you should have asked about. Have you tried binding to the `<Configure>` event?